# Comunicacion entre opencv c++ y Unity3D

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d

Tengo un problema que espero que me podáis ayudar en solucionarlo:

tengo que intentar pasar un cv::Mat de c++ a C# para convertirlo en un Texture2D. Es decir, yo desde c++ capturo la imagen de mi Webcam usando opencv. Una vez obtenido el frame en formato cv::Mat, tengo que pasárselo a C# para poder mostrarlo en un Texture2D. El problema viene que no consigo esa comunicación. os añado el código para que me podáis aconsejar. 
Un saludo y gracias

C++:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
void video(unsigned char  *ptr, int wid, int high)
{
    VideoCapture camera;
    if (!camera.open(0))
    {
        return;
    }
    Mat frame;
    camera >> frame;
    if (!frame.empty())
    {
        ptr = frame.data;
        wid = frame.cols;
        high = frame.rows;
        imshow("CAMARA", frame);
    }
}
```

Unity C#

```
[DllImport("NativoPrincipio.dll")]public static extern void video(out IntPtr Image, out int wid, out int hig);
            IntPtr im_ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            webcamTexture.Stop();
            int wid = webcamTexture.width;
            int hei = webcamTexture.height;
            video(out im_ptr, out wid, out hei);
            //byte* src = (byte*)im_ptr.ToPointer();
            Texture2D tex = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(wid, hei, TextureFormat.RGB24, false, false, im_ptr);
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\usortiz\\Desktop\\pepe.png", (byte[])tex.EncodeToPNG());
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

Comment: Yo no he usado OpenCV nunca pero...no sería mas facil usar [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) y trabajar directamente todo en c#?

Comment: tengo la obligación de utilizarlo, dado que despues de hacer este paso tengo que añadir una libreria de tracking ya creadad que utiliza OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

```
void video(unsigned char  *ptr, int wid, int high)
//                              ^^^      ^^^  

[DllImport("NativoPrincipio.dll")]public static extern void video(out IntPtr Image, out int wid, out int hig);
//                                                                                  ^^^          ^^^
```

Si tu idea es que la función `video` pueda devolver en `wid` y `high` valores es necesario que dichos parámetros sean referencias o punteros. Quizás funcione simplemente convirtiéndolos en referencias:

```
void video(unsigned char  *ptr, int &wid, int &high)
```

Comment: gracias a lo que ese apartado corresponde. Pero no consigo mostrar la imagen que capto. No estoy muy seguro si estoy usando bien el Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(...)

Comment: @UrkoSanchezOrtiz Si la función no es capaz de indicar a unity el valor de `wid` y `high` es bastante probable que unity no sea capaz de leer correctamente la imagen...

Comment: en C# el int wid = webcamTexture.width y el int hei = webcamTexture.height; me devuelven 320 y 240. y después de la función de vídeo me devuelven 640 y 480. ¿puede ser ese el problema?

Comment: @UrkoSanchezOrtiz yo no puedo probar tu código... deberás analizar si esos valores son correctos o no. Quizás en vez de empezar a probar con la webcam quizás deberías probar a enviar una imagen fija... o a probar la función de captura con un pequeño programa C++.

Comment: Creo que el problema no viene de ahí, creo que es que a la hora de mandar la puntero de la imagen no lo realiza bien y por lo tanto no puedo usarlo

Comment: yo creo que el problema viene en que no manda bien la imagen. dado que genero un fichero png para comprobar que es lo que me devuelve y es una pantalla en gris:

Texture2D tex = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(320, 240, TextureFormat.RGB24, false, false, im_ptr);
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\usortiz\\Desktop\\pepe.png", (byte[])tex.EncodeToPNG());

Comment: Hola, tengo un pequeño problema que espero que podais ayudarme.

Comment: @UrkoSanchezOrtiz Si es un error diferente al reportado por la pregunta te sugiero crear una pregunta nueva